# How to set/access tag value for Collection View with swift

Tags: swift

I have to use multiple collection views in one screen. So, I set the tag values for each collection views from storyboard and now I have to check the tag value from my code. I don't know how to get tag values of collection view.

Comment: What you have tried. show your code.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I'm just trying to check tag values of collection views inside Collection View Delegate functions. Problem is collectionViewName.tag can't be accessed. Xcode doesn't know/suggest 'tag' keyword. Now I replaced the names of Collection Views instead of tag values and it's doing well...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your collection views are all standard UICollectionView, and they are all placed on the main view of the UIViewController, you could use this

```
for view in self.view!.subviews
    {
        if let collectionView = view as? UICollectionView
        {
            print(collectionView.tag)
        }
    }
```

If you have customised the collection class, just change the test.
You will see if you remove the test condition, that you get the tag values for everything on screen.